# How do I reference an attribute inside the same object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to cut down on a lot of the manual typing id need to do when creating objects for a small program

currently the object structure looks like this:

```
test = [
  {
    entry: "001",
    name: "Name"
    image: `link/001`,
    types: ["type1"],
  },
]
```

what i'm trying to do is allow for automatic linking of the entry to the image using the this keyword but it's consistently coming back as undefined

```
test = [
  {
    entry: "001",
    name: "Name"
    image: `link/${this.entry}`,
    types: ["type1"],
  },
]
```

I tried creating a function inside of the object to create the result id want then return it but also undefined

```
test = [
  {
    entry: "001",
    name: "Name"
    image: getNumber(this) {
         return `link/${this.entry}`
},
    types: ["type1"],
  },
]
```

As well as this I also checked out various similar issues on stack overflow and they didn't seem to address my problem as expected

Comment: Use whatever you are using to fill the `entry` field.

Comment: I think making `test` an array is making things more difficult. Try `test[0].entry` - according to [this](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/113-javascript/11486-just-javascript-function-object-self-reference.html#:~:text=Just%20JavaScript%20%2D%20Function%20Object%20Self%20Reference&text=Functions%20are%20objects%2C%20but%20we,don't%20have%20immutable%20names.) (search for 'ans*' without the quotes), self-referencing should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea but the wrong syntax:

```js
const test = [
  {
    entry: "001",
    name: "Name",
    get image() {
      return `link/${this.entry}`;
    },
    types: ["type1"],
  },
  {
    entry: "002",
    name: "Name",
    get image() {
      return `link/${this.entry}`;
    },
    types: ["type1"],
  },
  // ... you can add more entries here
];

console.log(test)
```

In most cases it is actually easier to do this with a method such as map.

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Hadn't thought to use get image(), as it's one i wasn't aware of, thanks! this is going to be helpful in the future!